# RegEx para remover backslashes en un string excepto si están dentro de corchetes y llaves

Tags: php, json, regex, replace

Teniendo un string como el siguiente, necesito realizar un json_decode, el problema es que al usar stripslashes para quitar los `\` se quitan incluso aquellos que están en un json anidado dentro del string con formato json, es decir, aquellos que se encuentran dentro de `[{  }]`.

Esta es la cadena que me llega via POST en una petición donde se envía un JSON mayor, por lo tanto las comillas de este JSON anidado que se encuentra en la variable $_POST se encuentran escapadas para poder realizar el envío sin fallos.

EJEMPLO:

Cadena que llega en una de las variables $_POST:

```
$_POST['json'] = '[{\"IdForm\":53,\"fields\":[[1246,\"12.000\"],[1223,\"Si\"],[1218,\"\"],[1214,\"[{\"0\":\"2\",\"1\":\"4\"}]\"],[1209,\"5\"]]}]';
```

Para realizar el decode y pasar el string a array necesito remover solo los backslashes que no se encuentren dentro del valor del campo 1214, el cual es un json anidado en formato string (rodeado por `[{  }]`), de tal forma que quede así:

```
$_POST['json'] = '[{"IdForm":53,"fields":[[1246,"12.000"],[1223,"Si"],[1218,""],[1214,"[{\"0\":\"2\",\"1\":\"4\"}]"],[1209,"5"]]}]';
```

Pero si utilizo *stripslashes* elimina TODOS los `\` y me genera error al hacer json_decode.

Otra opción podría ser duplicar los `\` dentro del json anidado para ejecutar un stripslashes sin problema, pero sería dar más rodeos.

No tengo apenas experiencia con regEx, lo más cerca que he estado es esta expresión: `/(?<=\[\{)(\\+)?+(.*?)??(?=\}\])/g` ejemplo en: https://regex101.com/r/8XD4fl/1

Pero no solo he tenido que quitar los `[{` y `}]` de inicio y fin del string, sino que además he hecho un match interno del json anidado en lugar del externo, así que lo que llevo no me sirve.

Cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Comment: Por favor, aparte de publicar ese enlace, pon esa cadena de regex del mismo en la pregunta para que todo conste en la misma pregunta y no se pierda esa información por cualquier cambio en webs externas, gracias. Sino es posible que se pueda perder el contexto y esta pregunta no ayude a nadie más en el futuro. Pulsa sobre [edit] al pie de la pregunta para editarla y añadirlo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La regex sería `/\\(?![^{]*})/g`, ejemplo aquí: https://regex101.com/r/dW623k/1

Sin embargo, para adaptarlo a PHP he tenido que hacer algunas modificaciones en la parte de seleccionar el backslash:

```
$regex = '/[\\\\](?![^{]*})/';
```